# Can't find Jersey REST service on deployment

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey

I have a web app that hosts web pages, web sockets, and I'm trying to add a REST service. It's running on Tomcat 8 and I'm using Jersey 2.11 for REST. I'm using `ApplicationPath` and extending `Application` to register my service, and pausing in the debugger tells me that `getClasses` is being called and my handlers returned.

But for the life of me, I can't figure out the URL for the handlers. Everything I try returns a 404, except for the static pages I have, as well as the websocket handler.

Here is my `Application`:

```
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class RestApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<>();
        s.add(Test.class);
        return s;
    }
}
```

And here is my test REST handler:

```
@Path("test")
public class Test {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String testMethod(){
        return "test";
    }
}
```

`http://localhost:8080/webapp` will return my index.html. But I can't find the URL for my testMethod above. `http://localhost:8080/webapp/rest/test/testMethod` returns a 404 error. I've tried variations omitting parts of the URL, but without success. The URL mapping as I understand it is: `http://localhost:8080/<appname>/<ApplicationPath>/<Path>/<method>`

Is the mapping incorrect, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Just try http://localhost:8080/webapp/rest/test it should work

Comment: You can also put the `@Path` with methods, so you can have several methods in the class mapped to different paths.

Comment: @prashantthakre Did I claim otherwise?

Comment: @Kayaman no i didn't say in that way, it was just a conversation :)

Comment: Ahh, you were quite right! From the documentation, I had mistook how it mapped URLs to methods. I guess with only one GET method in Test, that is the default for /test.